# Can 吧 be used right after every other verb to indicate that one can go ahead and do that?

Tags: word

I know `你去吧` means that you can go ahead and leave the place where you are standing in. Thus I think `去吧` is also correct to cut off the word `你`. Like instead of saying the meaning `You can go`, you just want to say `yeah, go ahead`.

Can 吧 be used right after every other verb to indicate that one can go ahead and do that? Such as:

吃吧 (to indicate that you can of course start eating, no need to wait or to be scared)

看吧 (to indicate that you can of course watch/look at something, it is allowed)

说吧 (to indicate that you can of course say something you wanted to say, it is not wrong)

坐吧 (to indicate that you can of course sit down, don't be afraid, do like your own house).

Answer (score 1):

看吧 is more complex than your expression.

看吧 is often used on the context of showing "After all, What I did/told/spoke/said is right."

e.g.

看吧~~~往東邊才是對的。 (lengthen the sound of 吧)

看吧！就跟你說車子壞了。

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Your answer focuses more on the meaning of word `看吧`. It is useful for the word `看`. Thank you for that! But the main question is more about whether `吧` can be used right after any other verbs. `吃吧`, `说吧` and `坐吧` are correct to use to emphasize as mentioned in the question above? Looking forward to hearing that.

Comment: @OConnor 說吧、吃吧、坐吧, all your understanding are right, and these are very common in daily conversation.

Answer (score 0):

吧 is a final particle that can soften the tone of a speech, makes it less assertive and adds emotion to it.

> *Can 吧 be used right after every other verb to indicate that one can go ahead and do that?*

Beside implying: 'go-ahead' it can also imply 'let's'

Example:

> Man: 「我們一起殉情.」- "We die together in the name of love."

> Woman: 「你想死就自己去死.」 - "If you want to die, die by yourself."

~

> Man: 「我們一起殉情(吧)!」-- "(Let's) die together in the name of love!"

> Woman: 「你想死就自己去死(吧)!」-- "If you want to die, (go ahead and) die by yourself!"

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a decent Chinese-English dictionary.  But if you can read Chinese, this dictionary definition addresses very well:

> 吧 /bɑ/
>
> 助词
>
> 1  **用在句尾或句中停顿处，表示不同的语气**。
>
> **用于陈述句，表示不很肯定**
>
> 他大概已经走了吧 / 可以吧，先试试看。
>
> **用于祈使句，使语气委婉**
>
> 你回去吧! / 别说了吧!
>
> **用于疑问句，缓和疑问语气**
>
> 这笔是你的吧? / 会议结束了吧?
>
> 2  **用在句中停顿处，使语气舒缓**
>
> 他吧，身体不太好 / 你吧，就不用来了。
>
> 3  **用在假设复句（常常是正反两种设想对举）前一分句的末尾，表示两难或犹豫**
>
> 去吧，不好；不去吧，也不好。

Let's say 去吧 for example. Depending on how you use it,  it could be a milder imperative comparing to 去! Or it could express a kind of hesitation as in the example above (去吧，不好；不去吧，也不好。)